# Simple retrieving values from CoreData returns null for entities

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, core-data, null, entities

I have two entities. They are named SP and Code. I have 10 and 5 attributes in each respectively. I have inverse relationships on both the entities. I input the data into the model using the **firefox addon sqlite manager**. So **I DID NOT WRITE** a line like this
sp.coderelationship = codeObj; or code.sprelationship = spObj; anywhere in the code. Now in a viewcontroller i am retrieving data.
    self.spArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fR error:&error];

```
for(SP *spObj in self.spArray)
{
    NSLog(@"description is %@",spObj.sPDescription);
    Code *codObj = spObj.coderelationship;
    NSLog(@"it has value %@",codObj);
    NSLog(@" unique name is %@",codObj.uniqueCodeName);
}
```

The output is correct for description. It prints a value "xyz". But for the last 2 logs its null.
My Entities design

### SP

-sPDescription
-sPName
-sPID
**Relationship**
-coderelationship

---

Code
-codeName
-codeID
-codeDate
**Relationship**
-sprelationship

If more information is needed let me know. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before executing the fetch request add this code:

```
NSString *relationshipKeyPath = @"coderelationship"; // Set this to the name of the relationship on "SP" that points to the "Code" objects;
NSArray *keyPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:relationshipKeyPath];
[fR setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:keyPaths];
```

Also, have you verified that the relationships have correctly been inserted into the db?

Comment: Perchich. Thanks for the information. I added that code and still i dont see any values. Also how do i check if relationships have been inserted properly?I am still in the learning mode for Core Data.

Comment: You should find the sqlite db file into the application resource bundle. You can open it and check the tables' structure and contents with some sqlite browser (e.g. SQLiteManager).

Comment: @ Michele Percich. I did that step and i can do a inner join there and see that it can bring the data from both tables. Well my friend told me that if i write or set the relationship in the code then only i can retrieve the value or i cannot. Apparently i was doing an unwanted step in the project. I can skip that and set relationship in the correct step. That will bring me the required info as i have previously. Thanks Again.