# Core Data Table Relationship and Fetchrequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I am developing one iPad application using storyboard and core data.I have no good idea about core data.I have 2 tables names A and B. Table a have 2 fields with names datacode and price.In table B there are two fields with names itemcode and text.Table A have set limit.

Table A

datacode   price

p1        10

m1        17

p0        28

m3        20

w4        12

Table B

itemcode    text

p0          car

p1          bus

m2          pen

m1          ball

p0          ban

r1          book

m3          pencil

n1          tv

w4          radio

The values in itemcode in tableB is the data code in the table A + some other value.i need to fetch the text values from the tableB based on the itemcodes which values corresponding to the datacode in the table A.I how can i fetch the text from B based on this criteria.

Comment: @chris I am ne in objective C only 2 week experience.I need to do one project.I do not know the core data relation ship.Please help me .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use predicate with your  table A's datacode to table B's itemcode, like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *aEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"TableA" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
[fetchRequest setEntity:BEntity];

NSArray* fetchResults = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
```

you will get all the objects of TableA. so if you have one - one relationship with TableB, you can directly access the all the attributes like:

```
TableA *tableAObject = fetchResults[i];
NSString * itemcode = tableAObject.tableBRelation.itemcode
```

Comment: I tried this method but app is terminating and shows the error ....unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8cb09a0

Comment: no other method i am using here.My relation ship between the tables are one to one is that problem here?

Comment: relation ship between the tables are one to one: so in this case if you fetch the tableA is enough. look the changes in the above code.

Comment: i got all null values.where i have problem. In relationship or code?

Comment: I am using restkit coredatamapping to store data in the tables.All data are saved in the table suceessfully

Comment: I am not sure why you are using it....are you getting the values for tableA attributes?

Comment: sure the table A have full values

Comment: is need two entities have same attribute names

Comment: no no, it can have different values. when you are same the values to TableB, you should set the TableB object to TableA object and visa-versa.

Comment: you have no idea where i have mistake?

Comment: No, I think fetch is fine, I am not sure how you are saving the values.

Comment: keshav  i tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20014272/fetch-data-from-core-data-multiple-entities method ale. i both cases my relationship gives null values that is the reason i am fail to fetch values.

Comment: I have asked you to show me to code for saving the values. if you have getting null value means first check how you are saving it. is any thing going wrong while saving....

Comment: How code for data saved is related to relationship.In my tables A data code and Table B itemcode have no null values.I checked the data saved in the db by using coredataeditor.I am working as the part of the team so i have no chance to show codes...

Comment: ok, try to fetch the data for your Table B separately and if you can not getting then you can check for relationship...

Comment: separately i will get values from each tables no problem...I checked already.

Comment: ok. for relationship you should set your tables to each other like this:             [tableA setTableB:tableBOject];
[tableBOject setTableA:tableA];

Comment: i need to set key path for relationship? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096182/simple-retrieving-values-from-coredata-returns-null-for-entities

Comment: where's define [fetchRequest setEntity:BEntity]; ?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create relationship between your both tables A and B.
After that you have to fetch records based on you relations.....
You will fetch your records like this....

```
NSMutableArray *arrObj = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(TableB *tblObj in [TableAObj relationWithTblB]){
      [arrObj addObject:tblObj];
}
NSLog(@"Your records related with tableA = %@",arrObj);
```